# Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'struct'

Tags: matlab, economics

I am using the matlab to solve a simple model in economics. But I came across an error

Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'struct'

when I run the last line of code.

```
omega=mkt_share(Par,w,Grid);
```

It appears wired to me as I call this function repeatedly in the code before reaching the last line, it works fine. Could anyone inform me how to solve the problem? Thanks!

I post the full code of my program as following

```
clear all

Par.theta = 1.5;
Par.gamma = 6;
Par.beta = 0.1;
Par.zeta = 15;
Par.n = 100;
Grid.q = sort( gprnd(1/Par.zeta,1/Par.zeta,1,Par.n,1));
Grid.q = Grid.q./Grid.q(1);


w0=0.0001;
We0=tot_mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid);
mkt_share=mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid);
w1=0.01;
We1=tot_mkt_share(Par,w1,Grid);
while(We0*We1>0)
    if We0<0 
        w0=w0*0.5;
        We0=tot_mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid);
    end
    if We1>0
        w1=w1*1.5;
        We1=tot_mkt_share(Par,w1,Grid);
    end
end
iconv2=0;
tol2=0.0000001;
maxit2=1000;
it2=1;
while(iconv2==0 && it2<=maxit2)
    w=(w0+w1)/2;
    We=tot_mkt_share(Par,w,Grid);
    if abs(We)<tol2
        iconv2=1;
        disp('wage has converged in')
        it2
    else
        if We*We1>0
            w1=w;
        else
            w0=w;
        end
        it2=it2+1;
    end
end
if it2>=maxit2
    disp('Warning: Zero profit condition not satisfied')
end

omega=mkt_share(Par,w,Grid);
```

The code for function mkt_share

```
function omega=mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid)

omega=w0;

for i=2:Par.n
    rel_q=Grid.q(i);
    fcn=@(omega) (rel_q)^(-Par.gamma)*(omega/w0)^(1-Par.beta*Par.gamma)*((1- 
    ((1-w0)/Par.gamma+w0/Par.theta))/(1- 
    ((1omega)/Par.gamma+omega/Par.theta)))^(Par.gamma-1)-1;

    omega_i=fsolve(fcn,w0);
    omega=[omega',omega_i]';

end
```

The code for function tot_mkt_share, which calls function mkt_share

```
function tot_mkt_share=tot_mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid)

tot_mkt_share=sum(mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid))-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
mkt_share=mkt_share(Par,w0,Grid);
```

you create a variable with the same name as the function. From this point on, the function is no longer accessible, it is shadowed. The last line attempts to index into this variable, rather than call the function as you intend, because the function is shadowed.